# load data infile order by line

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv, load-data-infile

I :) 
I need to insert 13500 lines and +500 columns from csv.
So, I use load data infile and it's work.

But, I need exactly the same order in my MySQL database and my Csv.

Actually, for example, the 1000 line of the csv can be at the 800 place in my base

I need something like "Order by column1" but I don't find the clue.

Thank for your help

Ps : I have 2primary keys (ref of products) and the are not in the mathematical order (like 1, 8, 4, etc.)

EDIT : My code

```
$dataload = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.__FILE__.'../../../../bo/csv/'.$nomfichier.'"
            REPLACE
            INTO TABLE gc_csv CHARACTER SET "latin1"
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\t"
            IGNORE 1 LINES
        ';
```

I just take the csv and use data local inline with him... And the order is'nt perfectly respected, I don't know why...

My design Table

```
CREATE TABLE `csv` (
  `example` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `example` int(15) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `example` varchar(10) default NULL,
[...]
  `example` varchar(4) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`RefCatSYS`,`IdProduit`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: What exactly are you ordering by? I don't feel like there's enough information. Do you have any code samples?

Comment: Hi and Thanks. I have edit my post for show code to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the problem. In fact, the WS send to me a csv with a multiple couple of the two primary key. At the line 2365 and 9798, the RefCatSYS and IdProduit as the same. So the load data infile REPLACE the line 2365 by the 9798 and that change the order.

I ask them to send a 3th and UNIQUE primary key

Thank for your help, and sorry for the disruption.

Answer (score 1):

Add an auto_increment column to your table, with DEFAULT NULL. When you load data with LOAD DATA INFILE, there will be no value for the column, and it will get assigned an automatically generated id. Select data ordered by the column.

```
kostja@annie:~$ sudo cat  /var/lib/mysql/test/foo.csv   
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
mysql> create table tmp (example int primary key, id int unique auto_increment default null);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)
mysql> load data infile "foo.csv" into table tmp;
Query OK, 10 rows affected, 10 warnings (0.03 sec)
Records: 10  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 10
mysql> select * from tmp;
+---------+----+
| example | id |
+---------+----+
|      10 |  1 |
|       9 |  2 |
|       8 |  3 |
|       7 |  4 |
|       6 |  5 |
|       5 |  6 |
|       4 |  7 |
|       3 |  8 |
|       2 |  9 |
|       1 | 10 |
+---------+----+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't make an unique and default value field ... Navicat say "Incorrect table définition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key. If I add Unique, Navicat just renove checked "allow null" when I save.The first value of my new field, id_csv, are 12401, 12402 ... Why start by 12401 ?

Comment: You can't have two auto_increment columns in a table, yes. Notice that your original table definition in the question is incomplete - duplicate column names, and, apparently, missing definition of an important column. Remove the auto_increment clause from one of the columns in your table. After you load the data, you can alter the table and shift auto_increment clause around - remove it from the surrogate column and add it to the column you want.

Answer (score 0):

The tables in relational databases are unordered collections of records. You can get the rows in a particular order when you run a query by using `SORT BY`. If the query does not contain a `SORT BY` clause, the server returns the rows in the order they are on the storage medium. This order sometimes changes when records are updated. You must never rely on it and always use `SORT BY` (and indexes) to get a certain order of the rows in the result set.

`LOAD DATA INFILE` reads the lines from the CSV file and inserts them in the same order they are in the file. Apart from setting the value of an auto-incremented column (if there is one in the table), the order of the lines in the CSV file does not matter.